# Spring Security 3 - Not granted any authorities

Tags: ldap, spring-security, weblogic

i'm tring to use ldap for authentication on Weblogic Server but I have this problems always:

Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: WhgyMmQddKLfnFjhTLn5Thl421hWZ8sLV732ctYLSLhQpQLW1JFR!-860386732!1285980317840; **Not granted any authorities**

More details:

```
Oct 02 2010 00:45:25 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d4d8c77d: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@13b1fb5: Username: weblogic; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: WhgyMmQddKLfnFjhTLn5Thl421hWZ8sLV732ctYLSLhQpQLW1JFR!-860386732!1285980317840; Not granted any authorities
Oct 02 2010 00:45:25 DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@c00076, returned: -1
Oct 02 2010 00:45:25 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:71) [org.springframework.security.core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:204) [org.springframework.security.core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:98) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:95) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:36) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:178) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:106) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3242) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2010) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1916) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181) [weblogic.jar:9.2.3.0]
```

My security-application-context.xml:

```
<ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="ldap://127.0.0.1:7001/DC=base_domain" manager-dn="CN=Admin" manager-password="weblogic" />

<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapServer"
        user-search-filter="(uid={0})" group-search-base="ou=groups,ou=myrealm" />
</authentication-manager>
```

I'm using:

```
<spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

ANY help will be apreciated,

Ths a Lot!!!

Vinidog

Answer (score 2):

It could be one of :

- You may not be getting the "LdapAuthorities"
- You may have defined an access control for the page, which does not match the authorities obtained.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is just the output of the toString method of the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken which was used to submit the authentication request. You are attempting to retrieve username and password information from Active Directory which doesn't allow you to read passwords. That is probably why the authentication is failing, hence the BadCredentials event.

You will probably have to use LDAP authentication directly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved your problem. However, your description helped me to solve mine. I implemented the authorities mapper almost based on your code and it is working just fine. The only thing I can see that could lead to an empty authorities field is the field is empty when calling the mapper or none of the authorities in the argument map to your AD roles defined as ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN.

Answer (score 0):

You Manager DN is cn=Admin but you almost certainly need to provide a full and proper DN to the Admin user.